# How do I connect to my heroku shared database for postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, heroku

I have pulled the SHARED_DATABASE_URL from heroku config

```
SHARED_DATABASE_URL => postgres://username:xxxx@host.com/db_name
```

I am using pgAdmin to try to connect to it but it keeps on timing out.  Do I need to specify a port?  What am i missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot access the shared database using psql, pgadmin, etc.

> Heroku offers you the choice of running on a shared or dedicated database package. The shared plan is suitable for development and staging applications. It runs Postgres 8.3. The dedicated plans are suitable for production scale applications. In addition, the dedicated databases offer a number of advantages, **including direct access (via psql or any native postgres library)**, stored procedures, and Postgres 9 support.<sup>[[source]](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/database#shared_vs_dedicated)</sup>

Comment: Is there a workaround? Would I have to use taps to be able to use the data?

Answer (score 18):

You can use this command to connect to psql.

`heroku pg:psql`

Comment: you can also specify a database with heroku config variable as `heroku pg:psql [DATABASE]` , thanks @manish_s

Answer (score 3):

If you are happy to change to postgres 9.1 you can use the newly launched development database, which permits connections via normal postgres tools. Read more at https://postgres.heroku.com/blog/past/2012/4/26/heroku_postgres_development_plan/